# Runing two applications on the same port on nginx server

Tags: nginx-config

I have two nodejs applications runing on server: one on port 3000 and another on port 3001. I try configure my nginx server in such way that when I go to example.com I connect to first application and when I hit example.com/dictionary connect to second but when I try example.com/dictionary I get Cannot GET /dictionary/. Connection to first application is ok;

I make a try to connect application to another port and Application runs ok when I connect to port 8088 or 444

This is my nginx config file

```
 http {

        server {
                listen 80;
                listen 443 ssl;
                        ssl_certificate /etc/..;
                        ssl_certificate_key /etc/..;
                location /dictionary/ {
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
                }

                location / {
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                }
        }
        
        server {

                listen 8088;
                listen 444 ssl;
                        ssl_certificate /etc/..;
                        ssl_certificate_key /etc/..;
                location / {
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
                }
        }
}

events { }
```

Comment: This first has a similar setup as you, https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0

Answer (score 0):

I found what cause problem. Simply routes in ma application does not have /dictionary a the begining

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.